# How remove border to cell in a table?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3 and I want to remove border of cell:

```
<td colspan="4"></td>
```

This is the current table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>N°</th>
    <th>Fecha salida</th>
    <th>Fecha regreso</th>
    <th>Ciudad</th>
    <th>País</th>
    <th>Días</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr class="info">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>03/02/2015</td>
    <td>05/02/2015</td>
    <td>Ciudad de Panamá</td>
    <td>Panamá</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>05/12/2014</td>
    <td>05/12/2014</td>
    <td>New York</td>
    <td>EE.UU</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="bold">
    <td colspan="4"></td>
    <td align="right">Días fuera</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Current View: 
[image]

Desired View: 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to set the `border-bottom` css property to `hidden` for `<td colspan="4"></td>`.

```
<td colspan="4" style="border-bottom: hidden;"></td>.
```

...or include the css in your 'bootstrap overriding stylesheet' (if you have one).

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m7jct77e/)

Answer (score 1):

Use this CSS

```
#hiddenborder{
    border-bottom: hidden;
    border-left: hidden;
}
```